# AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='getStatusCode' signature='()I'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

When I'm trying to save or load my game with Google Play Games plugin (even if i logged in), logcat shows me this: [image: this error] Tried different ways to save the game, but it shows again and again. P.s. achievements and leaderboard works fine.

Here is script where I call save and load process:

```
     #if UNITY_ANDROID
 using UnityEngine;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 //gpg
 using GooglePlayGames;
 using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
 using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.SavedGame;
 //for encoding
 using System.Text;
 //for extra save ui
 using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
 //for text, remove
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 
 public class SaveManager :MonoBehaviour{
 
     private static SaveManager _instance;
     public static SaveManager Instance{
         get{
             if (_instance == null) {
                 _instance = new SaveManager();
             }
             return _instance;
         }
     }
 
     //keep track of saving or loading during callbacks.
     private bool m_saving;
     //save name. This name will work, change it if you like.
     private static string m_saveName = "game_save_name";
     //This is the saved file. Put this in seperate class with other variables for more advanced setup. Remember to change merging, toBytes and fromBytes for more advanced setup.
     private string saveString = "";
 
     //check with GPG (or other*) if user is authenticated. *e.g. GameCenter
     private bool Authenticated {
         get {
             return Social.Active.localUser.authenticated;
         }
     }
 
     //merges loaded bytearray with old save
     private void ProcessCloudData(byte[] cloudData) {
         if (cloudData == null) {
             Debug.Log("No data saved to the cloud yet...");
             return;
         }
         Debug.Log("Decoding cloud data from bytes.");
         string progress = FromBytes(cloudData);
         Debug.Log("Merging with existing game progress.");
         MergeWith(progress);
     }
 
     //load save from cloud
     public void LoadFromCloud(){
         Debug.Log("Loading game progress from the cloud.");
         m_saving = false;
         ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(
             m_saveName, //name of file.
             DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
             ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime,
             SavedGameOpened);
     }
 
     //overwrites old file or saves a new one
     public void SaveToCloud() {
         if (Authenticated) {
             Debug.Log("Saving progress to the cloud... filename: " + m_saveName);
             m_saving = true;
             //save to named file
             ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(
                 m_saveName, //name of file. If save doesn't exist it will be created with this name
                 DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
                 ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime,
                 SavedGameOpened);
         } else {
             Debug.Log("Not authenticated!");
         }
     }
 
     //save is opened, either save or load it.
     private void SavedGameOpened(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) {
         //check success
         if (status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success){
             //saving
             if (m_saving){
                 //read bytes from save
                 byte[] data = ToBytes();
                 //create builder. here you can add play time, time created etc for UI.
                 SavedGameMetadataUpdate.Builder builder = new SavedGameMetadataUpdate.Builder();
                 SavedGameMetadataUpdate updatedMetadata = builder.Build();
                 //saving to cloud
                 ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.CommitUpdate(game, updatedMetadata, data, SavedGameWritten);
             //loading
             } else {
                 ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.ReadBinaryData(game, SavedGameLoaded);
             }
         //error
         } else {
             Debug.LogWarning("Error opening game: " + status);
         }
     }
 
     //callback from SavedGameOpened. Check if loading result was successful or not.
     private void SavedGameLoaded(SavedGameRequestStatus status, byte[] data) {
         if (status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success){
             Debug.Log("SaveGameLoaded, success=" + status);
             ProcessCloudData(data);
         } else {
             Debug.LogWarning("Error reading game: " + status);
         }
     }
 
     //callback from SavedGameOpened. Check if saving result was successful or not.
     private void SavedGameWritten(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) {
         if (status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success){
             Debug.Log("Game " + game.Description + " written");
         } else {
             Debug.LogWarning("Error saving game: " + status);
         }
     }
 
     //merge local save with cloud save. Here is where you change the merging betweeen cloud and local save for your setup.
     private void MergeWith(string other) {
         if (other != "") {
             saveString = other;
         } else {
             Debug.Log("Loaded save string doesn't have any content");
         }
     }
 
     //return saveString as bytes
     private byte[] ToBytes() {
         byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saveString);
         return bytes;
     }
 
     //take bytes as arg and return string
     private string FromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
         string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
         return decodedString;
     }
 
     // -------------------- ### Extra UI for testing ### -------------------- 
 
     //call this with Unity button to view all saves on GPG. Bug: Can't close GPG window for some reason without restarting.
     public void showUI() {
         // user is ILocalUser from Social.LocalUser - will work when authenticated
         ShowSaveSystemUI(Social.localUser, (SelectUIStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) => {
             // do whatever you need with save bundle
         });
     }
     //displays savefiles in the cloud. This will only include one savefile if the m_saveName hasn't been changed
     private void ShowSaveSystemUI(ILocalUser user, Action<SelectUIStatus, ISavedGameMetadata> callback) {
         uint maxNumToDisplay = 3;
         bool allowCreateNew = true;
         bool allowDelete = true;
 
         ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;
 
         if (savedGameClient != null) {
             savedGameClient.ShowSelectSavedGameUI(user.userName + "\u0027s saves",
                 maxNumToDisplay,
                 allowCreateNew,
                 allowDelete,
                 (SelectUIStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata saveGame) => {
                     // some error occured, just show window again
                     if (status != SelectUIStatus.SavedGameSelected) {
                         ShowSaveSystemUI(user, callback);
                         return;
                     }
 
                     if (callback != null)
                         callback.Invoke(status, saveGame);
                 });
         } else {
             // this is usually due to incorrect APP ID
             Debug.LogError("Save Game client is null...");
         }
     }
 
 }
 #endif
```

............................

Comment: did you solve this, im getting the same by ticking the development build

Comment: Unfortunately, still not solved

Comment: I resolved mine and forgot about this comment, good thing you replied so that notified me, giving it as an answer hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the function header matches with the `Call()` or `CallStatic()` method. If your method accepts any arguments then you must have to create a parameters array and pass it to the `Call()` method. Else it will through the mentioned error.

Assume that, you have a [ICODE]PrintString[/ICODE] method which accepts two arguments.

```
public void PrintString(Context context, final String message )
{
    //create/show an android toast, with the message and short duration.
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Then you have to call the method in the Unity app like this,

```
 public void ShowToast(string msg) {
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
        // Retrieve the UnityPlayer class.
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

        // Retrieve the UnityPlayerActivity object ( a.k.a. the current context )
        AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

        // Retrieve the "Bridge" from our native plugin.
        // ! Notice we define the complete package name.             
        AndroidJavaObject alert = new AndroidJavaObject("com.codemaker.mylibrary.Alert");

        // Setup the parameters we want to send to our native plugin.             
        object[] parameters = new object[2];
        parameters[0] = unityActivity;
        parameters[1] = msg;

        // Call PrintString in bridge, with our parameters.
        alert.Call("PrintString", parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because I ticked the minify by R8
removing the tick resolved the issue for me and I tested it again enabling R8 minify just gives me the exact exception you have.

this option is at the end of `other settings` drop down at `player settings`
also this exception only happens when `Developement Build` is disabled